# click: function() doesn't overwrite

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, event-handling, popup

I have two buttons with each click event. The problem is when I click the button1, the alert message in the button1 event is showing. But when I click the button2 after the button1, the alert in button1 is still showing and happens vice-versa if I first click the button2 then button1 the alert in button2 is the one showing. The title, content and others except for click() and return() works fine. thanks for the help

edited: I think the problem have something to do with the unset() at the bottom of the function. I've tried different things like settings.click = undefined/null and the alert of the previous button doesn't show anymore but after that, no alerts shows anymore.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button1').click(function() {
    popup_box({
      title: "Message 1",
      content: "Message 1"
    }, {
      submit: "Edit",
      click: function() {
        alert("Message 1");
      }
    });
  });
  $('#button2').click(function() {
    popup_box({
      title: "Message 2",
      content: "Message 2"
    }, {
      submit: "Edit",
      click: function() {
        alert("Message 2");
      }
    });
  });

  function popup_box(options, settings) {
    var options_defaults = {
      title: "Popup title",
      content: "Popup content",
      footer: false
    }
    var settings_defaults = {
      id: false,
      submit: false,
      cancel: false,
      width: false,
      click: false,
      return: false,
      headerColor: "darkgreen"
    }
    var options = $.extend(options_defaults, options);
    var settings = $.extend(settings_defaults, settings);
    var popup_container = $('#popupBox');
    var popup_header = popup_container.find('.modal-header');
    var popup_title = popup_container.find('#popupTitle');
    var popup_content = popup_container.find('#popupContent');
    var popup_footer = popup_container.find('#popupFooter');
    var popup_submit = popup_container.find('.btn-primary');
    var popup_cancel = popup_container.find('.btn-secondary');
    popup_header.css("background-color", settings.headerColor);
    popup_title.html(options.title);
    popup_content.html(options.content);
    if (settings.footer != false) popup_footer.html(options.footer);
    if (settings.submit != false) popup_submit.html(settings.submit);
    else popup_submit.html("Submit");
    if (settings.cancel != false) popup_cancel.html(settings.cancel).removeClass("hidden");
    else popup_cancel.addClass("hidden");
    if (settings.width != false) popup_container.find('.modal-dialog').css("max-width", settings.width);
    else popup_container.find('.modal-dialog').css("max-width", '');
    popup_container.modal('show');
    popup_submit.click(function() {
      if (typeof settings.click == 'function') settings.click();
      if (settings.id != false) settings.id.submit();
      popup_container.modal('hide');
    });
    popup_container.on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
      if (typeof settings.return == 'function') settings.return();
      popup_title.empty();
      popup_content.empty();
      popup_footer.empty();
      unset(settings.id);
      unset(settings.submit);
      unset(settings.cancel);
      unset(settings.width);
      unset(settings.click);
      unset(settings.return);
      unset(settings.headerColor);
      unset(options);
      unset(settings);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="button1" class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
<button type="submit" id="button2" class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>

<div class="modal" id="popupBox" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="popupTitle" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove c-white" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="popupTitle">Popup Title</h5>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body" id="popupContent">
    Popup content
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="pull-left" id="popupFooter">Popup footer</div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to listen for a single button click, then get the id and act accordingly. No code duplication that way.

Comment: Could you please add the HTML necessary to generate the popup? This script is silently failing since the elements don't exist.

Comment: sorry for that. I just made my long code shorter and didn't see that. but that is still the problem

Comment: the popupBox html is added based on bootstrap modal